# Chrome Extension how to write file in Extension Directory

Tags: google-chrome-extension

This is just a quick question regarding chrome extension file writing.

Is it possible to write a file in the chrome extension directory?  (by that I mean write a file in the same folder where I have my manifest file and other scripts)

So far I have found out I can read a file in the directory via XMLHttpRequest but I have found no answer as to whether or not writing a file there is possible.

Thus far I have found out I could write files in the browser via the HTML5 file system API but to my knowledge that doesn't appear to write files in the directory of the chrome extension.

Comment: No, extensions can't do that. I think this is asked regularly, BTW.

Comment: Alright thanks, I'll try to do more research before asking another question.